# Syncronizing between online and offline databases in PHP based application

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, local

I have a CRM system built on PHP and MySQL, and want to make an offline version of it in case of any internet issues.

my point now is, I want to syncronize both local and online MySQL databases so that it won't be affected if the internet went down, but any update on the records in the local host or online appear on both local and online version of the crm.

Example Scenario, A lead is update through the online crm should be updated on the localhost crm once it is connected to the internet.
if the localhost lead is update on the localhost crm, it should be updated on the online crm as well once it is connected to the internet.

is there a way to accomplish this both databases are exactly the same structure and both are MySQL, the difference will be the lead updates, and new leads added

Comment: Can you show us some code you have tried?

Comment: if you want make offline version its possible to write it in .txt .html .csv etc... but when you want update offline files its not easy, may you wants make your offline database to do Create/Read/Update/Delete. you can install and config second database some thing like [mysql master-slave replication](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+master-slave+replication)

Comment: Are you asking if the client's internet connection is lost they should still be able to interact with your web application? Then, when their connection is restored their browser will push their changes to your server? If so, you can look into `Progressive Web Apps (PWA)` and `offline apps`. This is an emerging technology and is no small undertaking. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa

Comment: `I want to syncronize both local and online MySQL databases` - is a typical web application, there is no such thing as a local MySQL database from the client's perspective. They send requests to your web server which makes calls to your DB. If the client looses internet connection they cannot interact with your webserver or DB. You'll have to implement some mechanism client side (browser) to persist their actions and then push that to your server when the connection is restored. This is where PWA's come in.

Comment: This is actually what I'm talking about @waterloomatt, The Master-slave won't work as it is not one SQL updating another, but actually both databases will have updated records once the connection is lost, so it needs to be updated once the connection is back.. 
I like the PWA idea, will look more into that